# Install Stanford Core NLP

Tags: windows-10, stanford-nlp

I am tryingg to install stanford Core NLP on my machine havng windows 10, i downloaded the .jar file from official website and placed inside my xampp/htdocs/projectName folder, and added the Path of modals to environment variable, however when i run the command the command `java -cp "*" -Xmx1g edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP` it throw an error `Error: Could not find or load main class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLP`Any one knows what can be the issue?

Comment: How is PHP involved here?

Comment: i can not set up stanford server, any help will be very much appreciable

Answer (score 0):

You need to either set your `CLASSPATH` environment variable to include the directory with all the model jars and the jars from the distribution and get rid of the `-cp "*"` OR you need to put all of those jars into a folder, cd into that folder, and run your exact command.

The `-cp "*"` is saying to look at all jars in the current directory. So `CLASSPATH` is being ignored in your current command.

Comment: sorry if my response doenst make sense, i have downloaded my server from this link https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ its a simple .jar file, i extracted it in a folder, and inside this directory (\edu\stanford\nlp\models\)i found no jar files, can you guide me how to set it up ?

Comment: You should just download the distribution folder from the download button, and get a directory called stanford-corenlp-4.0.0 when you unzip it . That will have several jar files in it.

Comment: i downloaded that, but still having no luck

Comment: 1.) Go here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ and click the Download 4.1.0 button 2.) That will download a file called stanford-corenlp-4.1.0.zip 3.) unzip that file (or it may be automatically unzipped) 4.) you should have a folder called stanford-corenlp-4.1.0 that contains 46 files and subdirectories, 29 of those are jar files 5.) You need to set your CLASSPATH or use the -cp option to: /path/to/stanford-corenlp-4.1.0/*; (where /path/to should be replaced with the full path to that directory)

Comment: Info on setting CLASSPATH for Windows: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html

Comment: Or you can change the -cp "*" to -cp "/path/to/stanford-corenlp-4.1.0/*;" and it should work, where "/path/to/" should be replaced with the path of that directory on your machine.